# How should I display Pagebook Control in SWT?

Tags: swt, jface

I am currently creating a wizardPage like below.
[image]
The pagebook control was used to represent the comments in the figure, and the following code was written. However, it cannot be expressed in Pagebok.
How should I fix it?

// **Update PageBook**

```java
protected void updatePageBook(final Composite parent) {
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pageBook = new PageBook(parent, SWT.BORDER);
            pageBook.setLayoutData(createSubPane(getShell(), 2));
            availableSheetLabel = new Label(pageBook, SWT.BORDER);
            availableSheetLabel.setText(Messages.ChooseDomainFileWizardPage_12);
            pageBook.showPage(availableSheetLabel);
        }
    });
}

private Composite createSubPane(Composite parent, int numControl) {
    Composite result = new Composite(parent, SWT.NORMAL);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(numControl, false);
    layout.marginWidth = layout.marginHeight = 0;
    result.setLayout(layout);
    result.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That `pageBook.setLayoutData` call makes no sense at all, layout data should be something like `GridData` or whatever the parent layout requires.

Comment: @greg-449 I understand your comment and I remove'pageBoook.setLayoutData.Is there anything I can refer to to dynamically express the pagebook control?

Comment: I really don't understand what this PageBook is trying to achieve. The point of PageBook is to use `showPage` for several different pages. If you are just trying to add a Label dynamically it is not needed. The Display.asyncExec call doesn't seem necessary either.

Comment: @greg-449 As mentioned earlier, what I'm going to do is
1) If'Use Custom domains' is checked, the'Choose File' button is activated.
2) Click the'Choose File' button and select Excel (*.xls, *.xlsx).

Comment: @greg-449 3) If it is a normal Excel file, the contents of the Excel file are displayed in the form of a table in the PageBook area that I marked.
4) If you change the file, the contents of the Table control will also be updated. If you uncheck the'Choose File' button, the table in the PageBook area should also disappear.

Comment: @greg-449 I think the PageBook control is the right one for the displayed controls to change as I perform certain actions. But it is not expressed.

Display.getDefault.async has been removed.

Comment: Creating a PageBook and immediately calling showPage once and never calling showPage again is exactly the same as just using a normal Composite.

Comment: @greg-449 The label of the code above is an example, and there are many expressions such as label, comboBox, checkBox, and Table.

Is there any reason to use the PageBook control anyway?

Comment: PageBook is only useful if you are going to call showPage multiple times with different 'pages'

Comment: @greg-449 so.. If you select a normal Excel file, It makes sense to create a page to show the pagebook area and a screen to show the empty area when the check box is cleared, and add it to the pagebook control. If yes, can you give an example of such a case?
Please point me out if I understand something wrong.